# How to reconfigure an AWS ParallelCluster instance after it started

Tags: amazon-parallelcluster

How does one reconfigure values that were initially put to configuration YAML file that has been used to start an instance of AWS ParallelCluster?

In my case I simply want to remove the following snippets from partitions configuration as simply forgot to do that before starting the cluster:

```
Proxy:
  HttpProxyAddress: ....
```

I know that I can simply delete the cluster and create new one with corrected config.
But I am really curious if there is a way to correct configuration of a running AWS ParallelCluster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update a running cluster. You need to either stop your compute fleet or have a QueueUpdateStrategy set for the cluster. Check out the docs on this specific config parameter in the [User Guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/parallelcluster/latest/ug/Scheduling-v3.html#yaml-Scheduling-SlurmQueues-Networking-Proxy)

Comment: I'm afraid the very mechanism of changing the value of this certain config parameter is not clear to me.
After reading about the QueueUpdateStrategy I understand the strategy is about how a change to the value will be applied. It's not about how to change the config parameter value which I really need.

Comment: Assuming you created the cluster named `mycluster` with config file `cconfig.yaml`, you edit the parameter by changing it in the config file, then running `pcluster update-cluster -n mycluster -c cconfig.yaml`. [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/parallelcluster/latest/ug/pcluster.update-cluster-v3.html)

Comment: ParallelCluster is HPC infrastructure as code. Any significant change you want to make in the cluster architecture, you do in the config file. Then, you pass the file to the Pcluster software and it handles making the necessary configuration changes. This is the case for any configuration option marked as updatable in the docs.